# How to cancat query results into a text variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know about built-in functions that performs it. But I learn SQL and I want to understand how to make this without these functions.
I.e. I have the next code:

```
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR;
SELECT column_1 INTO @stmt FROM some_table;
```

How can I change this code to it stores all values in `@stmt` as a single string `'value 1, value2, value 3, ..., value N'`?

Comment: Where is `'value 1, value2, value 3, ..., value N'` coming from? Other columns. Or are the different values of `column 1`

Comment: Values are from `column_1`. I found a solution now using `FOR...IN...LOOP...END LOOP;`. Although, maybe, it has another solution.

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please show evidence of what research you have done thusfar, what you have tried, what you hope will happen and what is actually happening (including any error messages received).  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concat different values of column_1, then use this

```
SELECT string_agg(column_1,',') INTO @stmt FROM some_table;
```

Comment: I asked how to make it using SQL operators only without aggregation and other functions.

Comment: oh ok. didn't read the question properly. Without using other functions, your approach of for is correct.

Comment: Thank you for answer I try to make it using `FOR` construction. I voted up in any case because your solution is correct, of course, and I will use these functions. But the resolving of so tasks helps to get a language deeper, just as practice.

Answer (score 1):

After a some search I solved it so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table_names() RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
DECLARE stmt VARCHAR;
DECLARE temp_row RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR temp_row IN (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables)
        LOOP
            IF stmt IS NULL
                THEN stmt := temp_row.table_name;
                ELSE stmt := stmt || ',' || temp_row.table_name;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    RETURN stmt;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I don't think that it is the best solution even in my case but I couldn't find better.

---

**Much** better solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table_names() 
   RETURNS VARCHAR 
AS 
$$
  SELECT string_agg(table_name,',') 
  FROM information_schema.tables;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: This is needlessly complex and inefficient. Using `select string_agg(table_name, ',') from information_schema.tables` is a  **much** better solution.